# Caching linq 2 sql entities and related entities

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql, caching, c#-4.0

I'm caching the result of my linq 2 sql queries and I was hopeful that the related entities were also loaded and cached in the memory of my application(asp.net application).

Well this did not happen. The related entities were null.

Question: how do I make sure when I cache an entity `Product` the the related `Category` is also cached? Can this be done without having to explicitly cache the related category? Any comment will be highly appreciated.

thanks in advance
M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `LoadOptions` on the Datacontext to make sure they are automatically loaded

```
DataLoadOptions options = new DataLoadOptions(); 
options.LoadWith<Product>(c => c.OrderDetails); 
db.LoadOptions = options;
```

This example loads OrderDetails with products immediately.